# Does google cloud supports creating virtual machine using CentOS 32-bit OS?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I wanted to install CentOS 32-bit version as a Virtual Machine on Google Cloud.

I have tried several times by creating disk.raw and then gzipping that, copying into google cloud bucket and then when I try to create a Disk from this, it fails.

I am on Free Trial to ensure all things I want are supported and they work. The Google Support is Bronze, and that means they do not provide any support apart from the public internet documentation.

I browsed through all the sections of the documentation and I do not see anywhere any mention of 32-bit OS support. All standard images are of x64.

Hence I am wondering whether google cloud supports creating virtual machine using CentOS 32-bit OS?

Answer (score 4):

You can choose to build and run arbitrary OS kernels on Google Compute Engine if they are compliant [with the hardware manifest](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/building-images#hardwaremanifest).

More info here : https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/building-images

In the docs you find a reference for 32-bit OS :

- CONFIG_X86_PAE=y
  Set this option for a 32 bit kernel, as PAE is required for NX support. This also enables larger swapspace support for non-overcommit purposes.